# Should you really have to do that?

Tags: phrase-meaning

My question is whether this sentence is similar to or the same as the other one:

One day, a child caught his father disassembling one of his gadgets, to figure out what is wrong with it. The child said:

> Child: **Should** you really have to do that?

Is this the same as

> Child: **Do** you really have to do that?

Given the question at the beginning, is it possible to use these two sentences interchangeably?

Comment: Note that ***really*** is syntactically irrelevant to both constructions. It would probably be an "unusual" child who came out with the first example, but in practice it's unlikely there would be any difference in meaning (I kinda doubt the child really would be asking his father whether it's "objectively right and proper" for the father to do what he's doing). Certainly there will have been many instances where native speakers have (usually rhetorically) asked *Should I really have to ask?* or *Do I really have to ask?* with ***exactly*** the same meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are differences from the grammatical point of view and, as a consequence, in the meaning.

To convert a statement to a question, you invert the subject and the auxiliary verb. If there is no auxiliary verb, you add **do** as a placeholder auxiliary, then do the inversion.

> You have to do that.
>   Do you have to do that?

The only function of **do** in the second sentence is therefore to construct a grammatically correct question: it adds nothing to the meaning.

**Should**, on the other hand, definitely adds something to the meaning of the sentence. Looking at the definitions in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/should), the most appropriate is that should is **used to say or ask what is the correct or best thing to do**.

The first sentence uses **should**, and asks whether it is really correct that father should have to take the gadget apart. The exact interpretation is not clear and might depend on the age of the child and other factors. It might mean "are you allowed...", or it might suggest that, in an ideal world, fathers would not have to take their gadgets apart.

The second sentence uses **do** which has no special meaning, so the sentence is simply questioning whether it is necessary to take the gadget apart.

The difference between the two meanings is a small one, and some might question whether a child would be aware of the difference. Remember, though, that children are subject to much wider range of externally imposed limits than adults. A young child would probably only use the **do** version, or alternatively ask **are you allowed..** but if a child were mature enough to use the **should** version, they are probably mature enough to understand the difference.

In this context, the use of **really** is an example of a child's tendency to hyperbole which can easily escalate if the child doesn't get the answer they want: I have lost count of the number of times I have heard something like "Do I really really really have to go to bed now?".

On the lips of an adult, **really** can sound quite petulant. It is easy to imagine somebody saying the second sentence to their partner about a particularly irritating habit, when what they actually mean is "Please stop that!".

Comment: Excellent! Kindly correct me if my understanding about this question is right. >when the child asked his father+should, he knows that it is wrong(so it's like, he wasn't questioning his father but rather he was going against what his father is doing, in a subtle way of by asking?) right? Whereas,the asking child+do, implies ignorant-like question of the child himself

Comment: @JohnArvin, that is certainly one possible interpretation.

Comment: Thx. Got it. You're great

Comment: I suggest that 9 times out of 10, *Do you have to do that?* isn't simply questioning whether it is necessary to do it. It nearly always carries the strong implication ***Please stop doing that!*** And although using ***Should you have to*** instead of ***Do you have to*** could in theory carry some sense of questioning the *morality / correctness* of the action being queried, in practice it's unlikely - particularly in OP's exact context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: coming from an adult, I would agree with you about "Please stop doing that!". Children do copy their parents, and so if a parent uses that turn of phrase regularly to their children, a child might use it *in loco parentis* to a younger sibling, It would take an unusual child to  speak to a parent in that way:  Saffron in Absolutely Fabulous, perhaps.